# Node depth encoded as number of stars

Tags: lark-parser

Documents in this language look like

```
* A top-level Headline 

  Some text about that headline.

** Sub-Topic 1

Text about the sub-topic 1.

*** Sub-sub-topic

 More text here about the sub-sub-topic

** Sub-Topic 2

   Extra text here about sub-topic 2

*** Other Sub-sub-topic

 More text here about the other sub-sub-topic
```

The number of depth levels is unlimited. I'm wondering how to get a parser that'll build the nested trees appropriately. I've been looking at the [indenter example](https://github.com/lark-parser/lark/blob/master/examples/indented_tree.py) for inspiration, but I haven't figured it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem would require a context-sensitive grammar, so we use the work-around from the indenter example you linked:

We write a custom `postlex` processor that keeps a stack of the observed indent levels. When a star token (`*`, `**`, `***`, ...) is read, the stack is popped until the indent level on the stack is smaller, then the new level is pushed on the stack. For each push/pop, corresponding INDENT/DEDENT helper tokens are injected into the token stream. These helper tokens can then be used in the grammar to obtain a parse tree that reflects the nesting level.

```py
from lark import Lark, Token

tree_grammar = r"""
    start: NEWLINE* item*
    item: STARS nest
    nest: _INDENT (nest | LINE+ item*) _DEDENT
    STARS.2: /\*+/
    LINE.1: /.*/ NEWLINE
    %declare _INDENT _DEDENT
    %import common.NEWLINE
"""

class StarIndenter():
  STARS_type = 'STARS'
  INDENT_type = '_INDENT'
  DEDENT_type = '_DEDENT'

  def dedent(self, level, token):
    """ When the given level leaves the current nesting of the stack,
        inject corresponding number of DEDENT tokens into the stream.
    """
    while level <= self.indent[-1]:
      pop_level = self.indent.pop()
      pop_diff = pop_level - self.indent[-1]
      for _ in range(pop_diff):
        yield token

  def handle_stars(self, token):
    """ Handle tokens of the form '*', '**', '***', ...
    """

    level = len(token.value)

    dedent_token = Token.new_borrow_pos(self.DEDENT_type, '', token)
    yield from self.dedent(level, dedent_token)

    diff = level-self.indent[-1]
    self.indent.append(level)

    # Put star token into stream
    yield token

    indent_token = Token.new_borrow_pos(self.INDENT_type, '', token)
    for _ in range(diff):
      yield indent_token

  def process(self, stream):
    self.indent = [0]

    # Process token stream
    for token in stream:
      if token.type == self.STARS_type:
        yield from self.handle_stars(token)
      else:
        yield token

    # Inject closing dedent tokens
    yield from self.dedent(1, Token(self.DEDENT_type, ''))

  # No idea why this is needed
  @property
  def always_accept(self):
    return ()

parser = Lark(tree_grammar, parser='lalr', postlex=StarIndenter())
```

Note the `STARS` terminal has been assigned higher priority than `LINES` (via `.2` vs. `.1`), to prevent `LINES+` from eating up lines starting with a star.

Using a stripped down version of your example:

```
test_tree = """
* A
** AA
*** AAA
** AB
*** ABA
"""

print(parser.parse(test_tree).pretty())
```

Results in:

```
start
  

  item
    *
    nest
       A

      item
        **
        nest
           AA

          item
            ***
            nest     AAA

      item
        **
        nest
           AB

          item
            ***
            nest     ABA
```